# Prove $A^n = 0$ for some number n can never be invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to prove that a matrix $A$ with $A^n=0$ for some number $n$ can never be invertible.

My professor said to prove it with contradiction. Any hints?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: The matrix is nilpotent (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix)

Comment: $I=(A^{-1}A)^n=A^{-n}A^n=A^{-n}0=0$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove that a nilpotent matrix is not invertible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1539695/how-to-prove-that-a-nilpotent-matrix-is-not-invertible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For contradiction, suppose $A^{-1}$ exists such that $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I$. Consider $A^n(A^{-1})^n$.

$$A^n(A^{-1})^n=0$$

since $A^n=0$. However,

$$A^n(A^{-1})^n=\underbrace{A\dots A}_n\underbrace{A^{-1}\dots A^{-1}}_n=I$$

since there are as many $A$ as there are $A^{-1}$, which all cancel out. This is a contradiction so $A^{-1}$ cannot exist.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\det AB = \det A \det B$. Therefore, $\det A^n = \left( \det A \right)^n$.

Clearly, $\det A^n = 0$ would imply $\det A = 0$, meaning $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: What if we haven't studied determinants yet?

Comment: @Cesare Do you have the invertible matrix theorem? If so, which parts?

Comment: I know that a matrix $A$ is invertible if there exists B such as $AB=I$ or $BA=I$

Comment: @Cesare Nitpick on your definition, it should say "such that $AB=BA=I$". One can have non-square matrices $A, B$ such that $AB$ is an identity matrix, but we don't consider any non-square matrices to be invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A^N = 0$. If also $A=0$, you're done. Otherwise, there exists a maximal $n$ such that $A^n\neq 0$. Choose a vector $x$ such that $y := A^nx\neq 0$. Then $Ay = A(A^nx) = A^{n+1}x = 0$ since $A^{n+1}=0$. So, you have $Ay =0$ and $y\neq 0$. That is, $A$ cannot be invertible.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is invertible then so is $A^n$: it isn't hard to verify that $(A^n)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^n$. By contrapositive, if $A^n$ is not invertible neither is $A$.

If $A^n = 0$ it will fail to be one-to-one since $A^nx = A^ny$ for all columns $x$ and $y$.

Not one-to-one means not invertible.

Thus if $A^n = 0$, $A^n$ is not invertible. Consequently neither is $A$.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix $M$ is invertible iff the linear map $f_M$ associated to it is surjective. If $f_A$ is surjective, so it is $f_M\circ f_M\circ \ldots\circ f_M$, associated to $M^n$, and the invertibility of $M$ implies the invertibility of $M^n$.